# List indices must be not list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, typeerror

I need to take action when `pole[i][j] == 1`, but it throws an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

```
pole = [[0,1,0],
        [1,0,1],
        [0,1,1]]
for i in pole:
    for j in pole:
        if pole[i][j] == 1:
            my_code()
```

Comment: You're already iterating over the list just do `if j == 1:`

Comment: As @Pedro Maia already wrote you are iterating the list. Change your second loop to `for j in i:` and then you can check with `if j == 1:`

Comment: in your "action", do you need the indexes `i` and `j` or just that there is an action to take when the index `j` is 1?  Note you don't have indexes here though, `i` for example is a sublist of pole at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `for i in pole` which gets the actual values of `pole` not the indices. Here is the corrected code:

```py
pole = [[0,1,0],
        [1,0,1],
        [0,1,1]]
for i in range(len(pole)):
    for j in range(len(pole[i])):
        if pole[i][j] == 1:
            my_code()
```

Alternatively, you could use the values not the indices so:

```py
pole = [[0,1,0],
        [1,0,1],
        [0,1,1]]
for i in pole:
    for j in i:
        if j == 1:
            my_code()
```

Comment: Wow!  If I had only waited a few minutes before typing mine, I would have seen this almost identical version!  GMTA!

Comment: Deleting my version of this, lest I get the answer credit...  and I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 3):

a for-in loop iterates over the elements of a list, not its indexes. Also, note you have the inner loop performing the same iteration as the outer loop, not iterating over the the sublist:

```py
for x in pole:
    for y in x:
        if y == 1:
            my_code()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,technically speaking, given that `my_code()` does not use `i` or `j`, you could do something like this:

```
for _ in range(sum(map(sum, pole))):
    my_code()
```

The elements in pole do not necessarily need to be 0s and 1s - you could trigger other conditions, for example:

```
sum(map(lambda x: sum(y > 0 for y in x), pole)
```

Comment: That is why I asked about it. If `my_code()` is independent of "i" and "j" and one really just wanted to execute it the number of times `1` appears in the matrix then this or one like it is the answer.